# Rotate D3 symbol

Tags: d3.js

I'm rendering a d3 symbol that looks like this:

```
svg.append('path')
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(10))
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"; })
    .style("fill", "red")
```

I'd like to rotate this triangle so that the triangle points left `<|`. How can I rotate this symbol while keeping it at the same position in my viz? I've been trying to do the following, but the symbol moves to the upper left corner of my viz (it doesn't stay in the position created by the transformation):

```
svg.append('path')
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(10))
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"; })   
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)")
    .style("fill", "red")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the second call to set `transform` overrides the first value here:

```js
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ")"; })   
.attr("transform", "rotate(-45)") // Only this value will remain as the value of the attr
```

To fix it, you should append the rotation to the original value of `transform`:

```js
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + 100 + "," + 100 + ") rotate(-45)"; })
```

Another solution is to put the `symbol` in nested `g` elements and apply individual transforms to each of them, [example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute).